# Auto height problem in responsive web design

Tags: html, css

I am making a responsive login page and i did everything correctly this is my html code

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #c6faff;
  font-family: Segoe WP Black;
}
.form-box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 715px;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 400px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right top, #051937, #10325f, #184f8b, #1b6dba, #128deb);
  opacity: .8;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: black;

}
.form-left-side {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 337px;
  background-color: #fff1ff;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 400px;
  padding: 7px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  color: black;
}
.form-right-side {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 337px;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 15px;
  min-height: 400px;
  background-color: #fff1ff;
  padding: 7px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-left: none;
  color: black;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.text-field {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  opacity: .9;
  padding: 7px;
  background: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #2196F3;
  transition: .5s;
}
.submit {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ed00af, #f81795, #fc327f, #fb496c, #f65e5e);
  color: white;
  padding: 7px;
  width: 160px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Segoe WP Black;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .7s;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
}
.text-field:focus {
  padding: 8px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.submit:hover {
  border-radius: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px 20px rgb(0, 0, 0, .3);
  width: 170px;
  height: 60px;
  transition: .7s;
}
.text-field::placeholder {
  color: black;
  opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
  font-size: 13px;
}

.text-field:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
  color: red;
  opacity: .8; /* Firefox */
  font-size: 13px;
}

.text-field::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
  color: red;
  opacity: .8; /* Firefox */
  font-size: 13px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 730px) {
  .form-box {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    transform: translate(-0, 0);
  }
  .form-left-side {
    position: relative;
    width: 97.1%;
    float: none;
    display: block;
    max-width: none;
    min-height: 300px;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .form-right-side {
    position: relative;
    width: 96.7%;
    float: none;
    display: block;
    border-left: 3px solid black;
    max-width: none;
  }
  .text-field {
    width: 70%;
  }
}
```

```html
        <html>
        <head>
          <title>Form</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intital-scale=1">
        </head>
        <body>
          <div class="form-box">
            <div class="form-left-side">
              <center><h2 style="font-size:20px;">Register For Best Performance</h2>
              <p>When You Register at This Site You Can Use Our Features
                 And Have The Best Performance Here Thank You For Joining Us!<br>
              Never Foget This You Can Do Anything at This Site And
               This is For Everyone And We Won't do Building a Website For Just Somebody !
              </p>
              </center>
            </div>
            <div class="form-right-side">
              <h2>Login</h2>
              <form>
                <label for="fname">Username: </label><br><center>
                <input type="text" name="fname" value="" class="text-field" placeholder="Username" />
                <br /><br /><br></center>
                <label for="fname">Password: </label>
                <br /><center>
                <input type="password" name="password" value="" class="text-field" placeholder="Password" />
                <br><br><br></center>
                <center><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit">
                  <br></center>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

When I resize the screen down to 730 pixel that works correct but my text in form-left-side goes up and there is not something that I can scroll and my text first lines are not visible 
notice that i don't wanna take my min-height to lower and i want it to be 300 px if you can help me thank you

and loook also when it is runing on snippet on this site you can not scroll up so that is a problem
and my browser is opera

Comment: Center tags are obsolete and should not be used; that's one thing you should change .. (if you did everything correctly you wouldn't have a question??!.. ,, it's not the main reason for your issue.. sounds like a media query thing, but definitely worth changing...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem happens because you are absolutely positioning from the bottom of the page, changing it to top solves the problem. :)
Also you can add `position: relative` to your media query, to make sure it won't go out of screen. :)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #c6faff;
  font-family: Segoe WP Black;
}
.form-box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 715px;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 400px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right top, #051937, #10325f, #184f8b, #1b6dba, #128deb);
  opacity: .8;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: black;

}
.form-left-side {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 337px;
  background-color: #fff1ff;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 400px;
  padding: 7px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  color: black;
}
.form-right-side {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 337px;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 15px;
  min-height: 400px;
  background-color: #fff1ff;
  padding: 7px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-left: none;
  color: black;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.text-field {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  opacity: .9;
  padding: 7px;
  background: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #2196F3;
  transition: .5s;
}
.submit {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ed00af, #f81795, #fc327f, #fb496c, #f65e5e);
  color: white;
  padding: 7px;
  width: 160px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Segoe WP Black;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .7s;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
}
.text-field:focus {
  padding: 8px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.submit:hover {
  border-radius: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px 20px rgb(0, 0, 0, .3);
  width: 170px;
  height: 60px;
  transition: .7s;
}
.text-field::placeholder {
  color: black;
  opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
  font-size: 13px;
}

.text-field:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
  color: red;
  opacity: .8; /* Firefox */
  font-size: 13px;
}

.text-field::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
  color: red;
  opacity: .8; /* Firefox */
  font-size: 13px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 730px) {
  .form-box {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    position: relative;
  }
  .form-left-side {
    position: relative;
    width: 97.1%;
    float: none;
    display: block;
    max-width: none;
    min-height: 300px;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .form-right-side {
    position: relative;
    width: 96.7%;
    float: none;
    display: block;
    border-left: 3px solid black;
    max-width: none;
  }
  .text-field {
    width: 70%;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intital-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="form-box">
    <div class="form-left-side">
      <center><h2 style="font-size:20px;">Register For Best Performance</h2>
      <p>When You Register at This Site You Can Use Our Features
         And Have The Best Performance Here Thank You For Joining Us!<br>
      Never Foget This You Can Do Anything at This Site And
       This is For Everyone And We Won't do Building a Website For Just Somebody !
      </p>
      </center>
    </div>
    <div class="form-right-side">
      <h2>Login</h2>
      <form>
        <label for="fname">Username: </label><br><center>
        <input type="text" name="fname" value="" class="text-field" placeholder="Username" />
        <br /><br /><br></center>
        <label for="fname">Password: </label>
        <br /><center>
        <input type="password" name="password" value="" class="text-field" placeholder="Password" />
        <br><br><br></center>
        <center><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit">
          <br></center>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```